# How do we get a combination of cell results within start and end keyword?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I'm trying to extract the values between START and END as showing in the snap.

I'm not very good with Power Query or VBA, please help.

[image: SNAP]

regards,

Anish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new row in `B6:J6` with a series from 0 to N.
2. In `B7`, write

   `=INDEX($A$2:$J$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH("start",INDEX($A$2:$J$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),),0))`

   select `B7` and drag down
3. In `C7`, write

   `=IF(OR(B7="end",B7=""),"",INDEX($A$2:$J$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),C$6+MATCH("start",INDEX($A$2:$J$3,MATCH($A7,$A$2:$A$3,0),),0)))`

   select `C7` and drag to right and down.

[image]

Comment: thank you @PaichengWu. This answers my question. My question is on hold and I couldn't figure that out why. I'll try to implement your logic on a VBA and if fails, will try to post the question on another website. Thanks again

Comment: @anish.rossvilla - if you can't understand why the question was placed on hold, please read the links provided in the hold message. it will help you receive better help on this site.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman; thanks for your help. It states "Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be put on hold by experienced community members. While questions are on hold, they cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening." Someone was able to answer this query , so I'm ok.

Comment: @anish.rossvilla - yes, you were fortunate that someone took the time to help, but typically questions that show no original effort to problem solve are not well received on SO.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, I thought my question were not very well explained which is why that put on hold. You assumed no effort taken place prior to putting this question on a website. Lets do this, I need your help in solving the above problem in Power query. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @anish.rossvilla - I did not assume anything. I said "questions that **show** no original effort"... meaning, you did not tell us any of the code/functions you tried to solve it. If you review [ask] and read [Why is Please Help Me Not a Real Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) you will understand how to better help yourself in the future.